# Browse client side and server side files in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django

I have written a front end Django/Python application. It's like a syncing tool. Users can first browse the source and destination. Source is client's computer and destination is server's computer. The interface is similar to grsync. I need to implement it in the template(front-end application). How can I do this? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have this in my form.html(template for Django)

```
<form>
<p>Session Name: <input type="text" name="session"></p>
<p>Source: <input type="text" name="target"><input type="submit" value="Open"></p>
<p>Target: <input type="text" name="target"><input type="submit" value="Open"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
<input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location = 'form.html' " />
 </form>
```

Now when the user click on the open in the source the files and folders in the client's computer should be shown and when user press OK the path should be loaded in the Source field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
    <p>Session Name: <input type="text" name="session"></p>
    <p>Source: <input type="file" name="source"/></p>
    <p>Target: <input type="text" name="target"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location = 'form.html' " />
</form>
```

You need to have `<input type="file">` to bring up a filepicker.  But if you're uploading to a server, the user won't be able to bring up a filepicker for the server the same way they can for files on their own machine.  You'll have to write your own interface for searching through the remote filesystem visually, unless you can find a plugin for it somewhere.  Without a filepicker, the text field input for `target` should at least enable the user to type in what they want the name of their file to be on the server.  Hope that answers the question!